# about redirect in python crawling and extracting data from a webpage

Tags: python, redirect, web-crawler

[http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?execution=e1s1]

for example Tracking Numbers :LM920347139CN,
i want to extract the track history data,but it using **redirect** .
so how to figure out, it will be better if any ways to get data not containing presentation logic

Comment: What tool & framwork are you using for crawling?

Comment: @Pegerto,i am new , i use requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Apparently there are REST and SOAP APIs available for tracking. See http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/tracking/default.jsf

---

The easiest (non-API) way is probably to use the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module which you can get from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize). You use it like a web browser. It will follow the redirect for you and manage any cookies as required by this particular web site. Example:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber'
response = br.open(url)
br.select_form('tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch')
br.form['tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:trackNumbers'] = 'LM920347139CN'
response = br.submit()
html = response.read()
```

If you prefer to use `requests`, or if you need to support Python 3, `requests` will also follow redirects and manage cookies as required

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = 'http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber'
response = s.get(url)
```

With `requests`, however, you will need to set up the required POST form fields (which I do not show here).

Once you have the HTML you can use a HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to process and extract the required data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tracking_table = soup.find(id='tapListResultForm:table_2')
.
.
.
```

from which you can extract the tracking data.

Comment: ,thx a lot,it do help . sometimes i got webpage just json style, can  this web be extracted like that? i mean just dictionaries without presentation logic.

Comment: Not if you are scraping the web site. I strongly suggest that you look at the API documentation which shows that request and response bodies are XML.